# AngularJS ng-repeat orderBy / filter: function to call backend in one case, sort on frontend in other cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am looking for a way to use backend sorting of items on frontends view.

User picks selectedOption from a dropdown, and depending on his choice the correct list of items is displayed.

Most properties can be sorted using simple `ng-repeat & orderBy filter` in AngularJS. However, in one case, due to the complex unalphabetical order of chars I have to call backend to get list of items sorted and save some time (backend works fine).

Currently: When I click on a `Number` button (table column's header) and request is made, response is sent, nothing updates in the jsp view.

**Some ideas:**

- Can there be more `'orderBys'`?
- Can I simply call a function on click, get items from backend and update the `$scope` without reloading the whole page?
- Can those functions be somehow connected/mixed, like a `custom orderBy`?

**jsp table**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="orderByFormNumber()">Number</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('formName')">Title</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('type')">Type</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody ng-show="selectedOption=='itemsApproved'" ng-repeat="item in itemsList | orderBy:propertyName:reverse>
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.formNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{item.formName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tbody ng-show="selectedOption=='itemsForMyInformation'" ng-repeat="item in itemsForInfList | orderBy:propertyName:reverse>
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.formNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{item.formName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**angularJS controller**

```
$scope.ascending = false;
$scope.selectedOption = "";

$scope.orderByMe = function(propertyName) {
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
};

$scope.orderByFormNumber = function() {

      $http({  
          url: '/app/getSortedByFormNumber',  
          method: 'GET',
          params: {
              items: $scope.selectedOption,
              ascending: $scope.ascending
          } 
       }).success(function (response) {  
              switch ($scope.selectedOption) {
                  case 'itemsApproved':
                      $scope.itemsList.push(response.data);
                      break;
                  case 'forMyInformation':
                      $scope.itemsForInfList.push(response.data);
                      break;
              };
              $scope.ascending = !$scope.ascending;
       }).error(function (error) {  
            alert(error);  
       }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the items without reloading the page is the core concept behind Single Page Applications. So, you definately can :)

Firstly, I would put the HTTP call in a service, for concern separation. After that, before pushing the new data in the array, you should first clear them.
`$scope.itemsList=[];`. I don't know if you do it or not, just mentioning.

Another thing that I'm thinking is that, why you need a different array since there is no differentiation in the data that you actually show. What I'm thinking is that having a table with multiple `<tbody>` or a `<tbody>` that is toggling may cause problems because for some time the `<table>` doesn't have one. Did you check your console for errors?

Hope these help you somehow. :)

Comment: All right, I wasn't clearing the array. However now after I try to sort the table I get no results - everything disappears. Should I maybe use a promise? Also: I put HTTP call in a service. Also, no errors are shown in console.

Comment: Ok, instead of `push` I used simple `$scope.itemsList = response` and I added `$scope.preopertyName = null` in the beginning of the `orderByFormNumber ` function so any `orderBy` won't take effect. Seems to be working but will test on more data.